# How to keep a (Div with an Id or Class) hidden after accepting it's condition, using local storage?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make this Cookie-banner, the only this is missing how to save its hidden value to local storage, I can't figure out, how to do the right code so it would stay hidden after refresh. thanks in advance

```js
function cookies() {
    var x = document.getElementById("cookie-banner");
    if (x.style.display === "visible") {
        x.style.display = "none";
    }

    else {
        x.style.display = "none";
    }

    localStorage.setItem('cookie-banner', x.style.display = "hidden");
    console.log(localStorage.setItem)

}
```

```html
<div id="cookie-banner" class="cookie-banner" style="display: visible">
    <p>
lorem lorem lorem 
        <br>
        <a href="https://www.learn-about-cookies.com/" target="blank">Learn more</a>
    </p>
    <button id="closecookie" onclick="cookies()">Got it</button>
</div>
```

it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the initial value too on the page load, See the modified Js code below

```
 //get the initial value of cookie banner
 let initialValue = localStorage.getItem('cookie-banner');

 var x = document.getElementById("cookie-banner");

 // if it's not null then the value must have been set earlier
 if(initialValue){
    x.style.display = initialValue;
 }

function cookies() {   
    if (x.style.display === "visible") {
        x.style.display = "none";
    }

    else {
        x.style.display = "none";
    }

    // set the new display value if it's changed
    localStorage.setItem('cookie-banner', x.style.display);
    console.log(localStorage.setItem)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've refactored your code to this:

```
<div id="cookie-banner" class="cookie-banner" style="display: none">
    <p>
        lorem lorem lorem 
        <br>
        <a href="https://www.learn-about-cookies.com/" target="blank">Learn more</a>
    </p>
    <button id="closecookie" onclick="hideBanner()">Got it</button>
</div>

// Run on page load to show cookie banner
function showBanner() {
    var hideCookieBanner = localStorage.getItem('hideCookieBanner');
    if(!hideCookieBanner) {
        document.getElementById('cookie-banner').display = 'visible';
    }
}
showBanner();
// Hide cookie banner & remember setting
function hideBanner() {
    document.getElementById('cookie-banner').display = 'none';
    localStorage.setItem('hideCookieBanner', true);
}
```

Comment: I like the mindset behind this, thanks for the effort.